# Appium tests fails until rebooting IOS devices or appium tests fails due to webdriveragent getting uninstalled by itself- Any solutions?

Tags: appium, ios

My appium tests are passing before I checked it in and after I checked in the Jenkins code. However, after a few runs the appium tests starts failing and can't install the app on the ios devices. A reboot would fix it and sometimes if not I have to reboot the computer as well as the ios device. Sometimes the webdriveragent gets uninstalled by itself and I have to manually install it again. I didn't uninstall it though. Has anyone encountered this in Appium IOS automation? How did you solve this or worked around this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Added this in **BeforeClass**:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/local/bin/idevicediagnostics restart -u "+udid).waitFor();
Thread.sleep(60000);

capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 2000);
capabilities.setCapability("wdaConnectionTimeout", 500000);
capabilities.setCapability("wdaLaunchTimeout", 120000);
capabilities.setCapability("wdaStartupRetries", 4);
capabilities.setCapability("wdaStartupRetryInterval", 20000);
```

Settings this seemed to help!